# What do the different types of stability do?

Tags: the-division

So I have noticed whilst playing that a number of under barrel mods add to stability. Yet, I have found, so far, three different types of stability mod.

These are, Initial Bullet Stability, Horizontal Stability and Stability.

I think the names are quite self-explanatory, but how do these *actually* effect bullet spread? For example, I've had no issues with horizontal gun drift at all in the game, which makes the Horizontal Stability mods worth much less to me than the general stability mods.

So what do these actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different stabilities present in the game.

**Initial Bullet Stability**
The first shot from a rifle usually has more kick, which means that any Marksman rifle will benefit from mods with pluses to this stat. It'll make your first shot much easier to land, making followup shots easier.

**Horizontal Stability**
Some weapons will have a bullet spread pattern which jumps around from side to side as well as the pull upwards. Mods which increase the horizontal stability will help to control the side to side movement, making your bullet spread a straighter vertical line.

**Stability**
This is the general variant and effects bullet spread under sustained firing. Such as a machine gun will need a high stability to counteract the bullet spread as you fire off the whole clip.

[Reddit.com Gun Stats Explained](https://www.reddit.com/r/thedivision/comments/4ayt69/gun_stats_explained_stability_horizontal/)

Answer (score 1):

An AK47 will spray to upper right. So you can better this by using both need vertical and horizontal stability.
Try a lmg instead or a smg, they will spread differently. Watch the base stability bar on the right and how this increases with those mods.
Most weapons i use are just spraying vertical, but i.e. a socom sprays horizontal.

In General, and to answer your question, those mods improve the stability of the gun and reduce spray effects.

Comment: Can you update your answer to explain each type of stabilities effect on bullet grouping. Currently you're just stating the obvious.

Comment: Hm, what I wanted to say is, that it is dependant on the weapons you are using. Do some tests with different weapons against a wall or at the shooting range and you will see the differences of the weapons and mods. Ive just started a new char and with low level mods there is a high demand for counter measuring the guns spread, as I only can use stabiltiy mods with 2-3% right now.

Comment: @DavidYell This seems like a pretty direct answer to your question. What more are you looking for? You say in your answer the descriptions are self-explanatory.

Comment: I feel a complete answer would explain the effect of each type of stability and suggest a use for them. Such as initial bullet stability being most useful for marksman rifles. Perhaps I should answer my own question.